# how to do permuation between values of 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permutation

let s say I have a dataframe containing  tennis matches each match contains the name of the player 1 and the player 2

```
di={'player1':["adam","luke","roy"], 'player2': ["james","steve","derek"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=di)
df
```

> so I have something like this

```
player1   player2
0    adam   james
1    luke   steve
2     roy   derek
```

> I want to Randomly do a permutation between the 2 columns which something completely fine because the columns describe the same entity in the same context and have something like this

```
  player1 player2
0   james   adam 
1   steve    luke
2     roy   derek
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `sample`. Since `sample` works on rows, you need to do a double transpose to shuffle columns:

```
>>> df.T.sample(frac=1).T

  player2 player1
0   james    adam
1   steve    luke
2   derek     roy
```

Comment: no, it doesn't do the permutation between the column values it just randomly shuffles the order of the columns